# Date And Multiple Field Filter Through SPATIE query builder for post request In Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I go through 'SPATIE query builder' documentation and find they cannot describe properly how to post methods implemented. I need to filter data based on multiple parameters including the data add date filter, and I am using the POST method, How I can achieve this for 'SPATIE query builder'.

I can Filter 1 field by writing below code

```
$data = QueryBuilder::for(EmpData::where('empAddedByAgent', $request->searchAgent))
                ->get();
```

The form Look Like Below Image
[image]